# Using exec() in php to compile a .java file

Tags: php

I am using `file_get_contents()` to get a .java file into a textarea which works just fine. Once this occurs the user edits the file and submits this new code.

For as much as i have tried to read on the topic of the exec() function in php i believe it can be used to compile a .java file as well as execute it. I would only like to compile this .java file and would like to have an alert if the file could not be compiled and therefore not submit.

Is is possible to do so with the exec() command or any other commands in php or am i looking in the wrong direction? thanks.

Comment: Not possible. Totally not possible.

Comment: > `If exec is your answer. You are asking the wrong question` <

Comment: Please don't feed the "exec is evil" band-wagon. Exec is EVIL if you don't know what your doing. Also I wouldn't say its not possible, but wouldn't you need to compile the whole java package instead?

Answer (score 1):

I have try to use `shell_exec()`, but I just output the file result. This is my code:

```
$fileName = $f_file.".java";
$filePath = "./java_file/";
$openFile = fopen($filePath.$fileName, 'w');
fwrite($openFile, $code);

//compile file
exec("cd /opt/lampp/htdocs/javaPro/java_file; javac {$fileName} 2>&1", $output, $resultCode);

// compile have wrong
if ($resultCode) {
  echo implode("\n", $output);
}

// compile success
else {
  $excuteResult = shell_exec("cd /opt/lampp/htdocs/javaPro/java_file; java {$f_file} 2>&1");
  echo $excuteResult;
}
```